# How can make a ternary operator in a ng-model? Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

When I add a new dynamic text field, I add it with "0", by default, I would like to do something so that if the value is "0", replace it with "".

```
     $scope.add=function(){
          $scope.aAnimals.push({ "animal": "0"})
     }

    <div ng-repeat='item in aAnimals'>
     THIS IS MY IDEA in ng-model but i have an error..<!--item.animal=='0'?'':item.animal-->  
    <input type='text' ng-model=item.animal class='animal' />
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ukTl0ho5gPpOE6jMLq11?p=preview

Comment: You should not do that. Can you tell what you want to achieve? You can do other way.

Comment: Might be obvious but why not just `$scope.aAnimals.push({ "animal": ""})`

Comment: @phuzi not can have by default "animal": "", this generate a problem with the dropdown

Comment: @yavg If the property name is different then you won't be able to use a ngRepeat - don't believe there's a way to bind a different property using ngModel. Got a feeling you're trying to solve a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create filter for that:

```
app.filter('blankZero', function () {
  return function (text) {

    if(text=="0") 
        return "";

    return text;
  };
});
```

Use it in view:

```
{{item.animal|blankZero}}
```

Comment: where use {{item.animal|blankZero}}?

Comment: @yavg in template inside ng-repeat

Comment: You are using ng-model in wrong way should be ng-model="item.animal|blankZero"

Comment: it not works for me... http://plnkr.co/edit/ukTl0ho5gPpOE6jMLq11?p=preview

Comment: I don't get fully Your idea, but I tried to do somthing with Your plunker, here You go -http://plnkr.co/edit/rHozICz4ruZCuXUgHZlt?p=preview